# Angular app routing errors in production

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My site works fine on the dev server but when I publish it to production on GitHub pages it has a strange error. Entering the URL (yanshuf0.github.io/portfolio) brings up the page fine, however when I type in yanshuf0.github.io/portfolio/home the page fails to load and produces the following console log.

[image: console errors]

It seems to be an error at home but I don't get it since the base URL redirects to the home URL where there are no problems...

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent},
  { path: 'blog-post', component: BlogPostComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
])
```

Anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

Edit: to clarify this issue doesn't occur on the development server.
Edit2: the error doesn't occur when I enter yanshuf0.github.io/portfolio/home/ with the trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your "base href" in your index.html to portfolio, or whatever your project name is.

```
<base href="/portfolio/">
```

Comment: I'll give that a try one moment.

Comment: Seems to have fixed the issue. What's the logic on why the omission would produce this behavior?

Comment: That's the way Angular is designed. In dev, you run your app in the root context, whereas when you deploy it to github, you run it under a different context. That's why you see different behaviors from dev vs "production". So, to clarify, when you run an angular app in a context/path that is not the root ("/"), you need to specify base href.